# Unamed Categories and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, categories

I have code such as the following which doesn't work unless the category name is left blank

PrivatePropertyTest.h

```
@interface PrivatePropertyTest : NSObject
@property (readonly) int readonly;
- (void) testMethod;
@end
```

PrivatePropertyTest.m

```
#import "PrivatePropertyTest.h"
@interface PrivatePropertyTest (/*If I place a name in here it doesn't work*/)
@property (readwrite) int readonly;
@end

@implementation PrivatePropertyTest
@synthesize readonly;
- (void) testMethod
{
    self.readonly = 2;
}
@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PrivatePropertyTest.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        PrivatePropertyTest *pPT = [[PrivatePropertyTest alloc] init];
        [pPT testMethod];
        //pPT.readonly = 1;

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I give it a name is says the setter Method for the selector doesn't exist.  Does this have to do with name mangling? Why does it matter if I name it or not?

If you can declare unnamed categories like this, can more than one unnamed category be declared for the same class?

Comment: Why are you redeclaring the interface in your implementation file?

Comment: Just to redeclare the properties as read write only to the implementation code itself, not to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, is that isn't an unnamed category. It's a class extension.

Class extensions are a bit like categories in that you can declare methods and properties for the class to implement. But extensions are actually part of the main implementation of the class. This means you can do things like override property access behavior (what you are doing) or add ivars.

Class extensions are required to be compiled with the implementation block, and there can only be one of them.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense :-)